# I can not generate iReport report in php java bridge

Tags: php, xampp, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

use tomcat-7 for Java Bridge,
xampp for php phpMyAdmin,
iReport 5.6 for the design
and I included libraries JasperReport-library-6.1.1 for javabridge.

Already set the CATALINA_HOME, JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, PHP_HOME and path =% php_home% for environment variables.

the report in iReport working 100% and normal php script.

but when I go to generate the report with php java bridge it gives me an error. and no longer can be. I'm new at this, if I can give a help, thank you.

I apologize for my English

error:

```
Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba_report\index.php on line 24

Warning: require_once(http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba_report\index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba_report\index.php on line 24
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your php.ini, yoçu need to enable allow_url_include=On

Answer (score -1):

Replace `require_once(http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc)` with `require_once '../JavaBridge/java/Java.inc'` in the index.php file.